# When to inform my manager that I want to leave in one year from now?

Tags: software-industry, resignation, manager, software-development, software

I have been working in this company for the past 3 years. This is my first job, I started it as an intern while I was studying for faculty. I was then hired as Software Junior, and this year I was promoted to Software Engineer.

I like the team and what I am working on, but I don't like the town. I want to move back to my hometown, that I prefer and where my friends and family are. I've decided the best time to do so is next year.

We are 3 people (including the manager) in the team, working on a huge project. 
Should I inform my manager of the leaving as soon as possible or only once I found another job and have a contract with the other company?

Comment: What does your contract say your notice period is? Give no more notice that your contract specifies.

Comment: Also a thing to consider, knowing you're leave in 1 year, if they fire you say in 2 months after this major project is completed, will you be able to support yourself till you move back home and find a new job?

Comment: If you like the team, have you considered asking if you could work remote? If your manager and whomever else in the chain of command agrees, this could be a win-win.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, the best policy is to **make your future plans (move, new job, whatever) and get everything finalized, *then* tell your employer.** In other words, wait until you have your living situation and your job in your new city all taken care of - in writing. The limiting factor on this in the very short term is ensuring you respect the notice period in your contract, if there is one, or the cultural/industry norms. For instance, in my culture and industry, it's typical to give 2 weeks notice.

The danger in letting your employer know any earlier than that is, they may "write you off" as expendable. If you are planning a move to another city, and a new job, it may take a while before everything clicks and you find a new job, etc. If you tell your employer ahead of time, and they decide to replace you immediately (on *their* timeline, instead of yours) - you could be put in a very bad spot if your plans change - you have trouble finding a new job, your lease on your new apartment gets pushed back, whatever.

If you already have a new job (in writing - a contract or signed offer letter), you know where you're going to live, and all the details are final, and you don't mind the chance that you'll become unemployed at some point in the next year - you can go ahead and tell your employer. Otherwise, wait until your typical notice period.

Answer (score 10):

Rule of thumb: Only inform (give notice) after you have secured another contract. Not before that.

Plans change (in a matter of days or weeks), and a year ahead is too much. There's nothing "good" you can achieve by disclosing your plans ahead of time. Any good organization MUST have a backup contingency plan and that is considered in the "official notice period". You'll not be doing any "favor" to the organization by proving them with the information that you are planning to leave.

**Remember one (hard) truth:** You don't have friends in the workplace, only people who are friendly.

Answer (score 1):

The time to notify your manager is after you have signed a written offer from a new company.  The notice period you give will depend on your current contract.

Even though you are thinking about what you will be doing in a year, there is no guarantee that everything will go according to your plans.  Do not tell your manager until you officially have a new job.

Comment: I don't think it's exactly accurate. If you sign a contract to start working for another company a year from now, and your existing company decides to find your replacement in 3 months, that leaves you 9 months without a job.

Comment: Though I suppose this depends on the exact employment conditions.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie After you have signed an offer means anytime after, not the exact moment.  It all obviously depends on OP's new start date and current notice period.